# Javascript declaring and initializing variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I understand that when a variable is declared it is given the value "undefined", but I don't understand why the following code doesn't work (returns NaN):

```
function sum() {
// return the sum of all arguments given.
  var answer;
  for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    answer += (arguments[i]);
  }
  console.log(answer);
}
sum(4,5,3,2);
```

In order to get the correct answer (14), I had to initialize the *answer* variable:

```
var answer = 0;
```

Comment: Try to add `parseInt` like `parseInt(arguments[i])` and `var answer=0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you're asking why `undefined + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2` is `NaN` (not a number). The answer is that, when you treat `undefined` as a number, it is implicitly converted to `NaN`. Any operation on `NaN` will, in turn, result in `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: you cannot add to "undefined". The answer is... undefined, or not a number. You *can*, however, add to zero, so of course you have to initialize the variable to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer += (arguments[i]);
```

equals

```
answer = answer + (arguments[i])
```

`answer` being initially undefined, you actually have

```
answer = undefined + (arguments[i])
```

which is a NaN:

```js
alert(undefined + 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to add a number to an undefined variable this is not possible because you are trying to add a number to answer which isn't a number until you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving answer uninitialized is equivalent to

```
var answer = undefined;
```

And since (undefined + any number) is also NaN (not a number) each loop does nothing but keep reassigning answer to NaN

```
console.log(undefined + 0); => NaN
console.log(NaN + 1); => NaN
console.log(NaN + 2); => NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `undefined + 1` (a variable not initialized resolves to `undefined`) in the console: its result is `NaN` (Not a Number), so any next iteration `NaN` + some number will be `NaN`.

Alternatively you can use `Array.reduce` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more on that) to calculate the sum:

```js
function sum() {
  // return the sum of all arguments given.
  return ([].slice.call(arguments)).reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}

document.querySelector('#result')
  .innerHTML = '<code>sum(1,4,3,5,6)</code> =&gt; ' + sum(1, 4, 3, 5, 6);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```